# Storing and retrieving data in tuc file

Tags: context, programming, context-mkiv

I want to store some data in the `.tuc` file, which is being picked up in the next run. I suceeded in storing some values but I failed in retrieving them afterwards.

Here is my attempt:

```
\starttext
\startluacode
local collected = utilities.storage.allocate()
local tobesaved = utilities.storage.allocate()

job.register("job.userdata", tobesaved)

tobesaved["foo"] = "value_foo"
tobesaved["bar"] = "value_bar"
\stopluacode
\stoptext
```

This leads to the following entry in the `.tuc` file:

```
utilitydata.job.userdata={
 ["bar"]="value_bar",
 ["foo"]="value_foo",
}
```

The two values are stored as desired.

Side question: I randomly picked the table `utilitydata.job.userdata` to store my values. Is there a default table which should be used for this to avoid clashes with the ones used by the system?

I expected to be able to retrieve the data with e.g. `collected["foo"]`, but the `collected` table is empty.

The sources tell me that `job.register` has four arguments: `collected`, `tobesaved`, `initializer` and `finalizer`. Maybe that is where my mistake is. I don't know what they are doing.

What is the interface to retrieve the values from the `.tuc` file?

<del>*(I don't know if the question is ConTeXt centric or generally applies to LuaTeX. If the mechanism is ConTeXt related, feel free to add the [context](/questions/tagged/context) tag.)*</del>

Comment: There was a recent message on dev-context mailing list by Hans giving a complete example of how to use `job.register` and a new feature that allows you to add two pass data from the tex side. Unfortunately, the dev-context archives are only accessible to members. So, you'll need to join the list to view the message.

Comment: @Aditya I am subscribed to dev-context, but frankly, I often don't read it thoroughly. However, I fail to find Hans' mail. Grepping the archive for `job.register` returns nothing. Could you give a pointer? [gmane](http://gmane.org/) hosts the [list archive](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.context.devel) also for non-members.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that that discussion was off-list. I'll post the gist of it as an answer.

Comment: The code needs to be loaded at the time you are generating the format to work. Please wait until the next beta for an alternative implementation of two-pass data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Defining a data set

To store values to the `.tuc` file you can use `\definedataset [myset]` to
define a container for the data.

## Storing data

To store key-value pairs use the command `\setdataset`.

```
    \setdataset [myset] [foo=foo-first,  bar=bar-first]
    \setdataset [myset] [foo=foo-second, bar=bar-second]
    \setdataset [myset] [foo=foo-third,  bar=bar-third]
```

Subsequent calls with the same keys to different data like in the example
above does not overwrite the former values. *All* values are stored and
enumerated. The calls above lead to the following entries in the `.tuc` file.

```
utilitydata.job.datasets.collected={
 ["myset"]={
  {
   ["bar"]="bar-first",
   ["foo"]="foo-first",
  },
  {
   ["bar"]="bar-second",
   ["foo"]="foo-second",
  },
  {
   ["bar"]="bar-third",
   ["foo"]="foo-third",
  },
 },
}
```

The system takes care of the name of the table not to interfere with core tables.

One can also add another parameter to address the individual values (with the
same keys) from subsequent calls.

```
\setdataset [myset] [first]  [foo=foo-first,  bar=bar-first]
\setdataset [myset] [second] [foo=foo-second, bar=bar-second]
\setdataset [myset] [third]  [foo=foo-third,  bar=bar-third]
```

These calls with the additional parameter lead to the following entries in the `.tuc` file.

```
utilitydata.job.datasets.collected={
 ["myset"]={
  ["first"]={
   ["bar"]="bar-first",
   ["foo"]="foo-first",
  },
  ["second"]={
   ["bar"]="bar-second",
   ["foo"]="foo-second",
  },
  ["third"]={
   ["bar"]="bar-third",
   ["foo"]="foo-third",
  },
 },
}
```

## Retrieving the values

The values can be retrieved with the `\datasetvariable` command. The first
argument is the data set defined with `\definedataset`.

The second argument is a number if the first variant with two parameters of
`\setdataset` was used. It's the number of the `\setdataset` call. If the
second variant with three parameters was used, then it is the identifier given
in the second argument.

And the third argument is the key which value should be retrieved.

*Note:* In contrast to the other mentioned commands, the arguments of
`\datasetvariable` are delimited by braces, instead of brackets, because the
actually *typeset* data. That's ConTeXts convention.

## Complete example

```
\starttext

    \definedataset [myset-1]

    % two arguments ⇒ the data is accessed by number
    \setdataset    [myset-1] [foo=foo-first,  bar=bar-first]
    \setdataset    [myset-1] [foo=foo-second, bar=bar-second]

    % Outputs foo-first
    \datasetvariable{myset-1}{1}{foo}\par

    % Outputs foo-second
    \datasetvariable{myset-1}{2}{foo}\par

    % Outputs bar-first
    \datasetvariable{myset-1}{1}{bar}\par

    % Outputs bar-second
    \datasetvariable{myset-1}{2}{bar}\blank


    \definedataset [myset-2]

    % three arguments ⇒ the data is accessed by identifier
    \setdataset    [myset-2] [first]  [alpha=alpha-first,  beta=beta-first]
    \setdataset    [myset-2] [second] [alpha=alpha-second, beta=beta-second]

    % Outputs alpha-first
    \datasetvariable{myset-2}{first} {alpha}\par

    % Outputs alpha-second
    \datasetvariable{myset-2}{second}{alpha}\par

    % Outputs beta-first
    \datasetvariable{myset-2}{first} {beta}\par

    % Outputs beta-second
    \datasetvariable{myset-2}{second}{beta}\par

\stoptext
```

Result: [image: result]