# How to retrieve a value which is set later on in the document?

Tags: context, context-mkiv

According to [What is the recommended way to assign a value to a variable and retrieve it for later use?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37094/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-assign-a-value-to-a-variable-and-retrieve-it-for), in ConTeXt, one can use `\setvalue{name}{value}` to set a value and `\getvalue{name}`, to retrieve that value later. This seems to only work if `\setvalue` is used before `\getvalue` is needed. How can I retrieve a value early on in a document, when the value is set much later in the document?

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52067/storing-and-retrieving-data-in-tuc-file

Comment: Also worth reading: [Context wiki - Multi-pass data](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/System_Macros/Key_Value_Assignments#Multi-pass_data)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What Marco said: use ConTeXt's multi-pass data mechanism. Here's how.

```
% Define a dataset that will store our key-value tables
\definedataset[mydataset]

\starttext

\framed[
    % Here we use \datasetvariable to retrieve the values of myheight and mywidth. 
    % Notice that we only define those values further on in the document.
    % Notice also that we don't worry about the first pass: through some black magic,
    % we don't get 'variable undefined' problems.
    % Ah, the wonders of automatic multi-pass compiling.
    height=\datasetvariable{mydataset}{mytable}{myheight},
    width=\datasetvariable{mydataset}{mytable}{mywidth}
]{
    This is my text in a framed box
}

% Observe how we define myheight and mywidth here at the end, 
% *after* having already invoked their values.
\setdataset[mydataset][mytable][myheight=3cm, mywidth=3cm]

\stoptext
```

Typically `myheight` and `mywidth` would depend on the height or width of some other object in the document, but I can't be bothered to muck around with boxes for this example.

Answer (score 4):

The OP asked for a ConTeXt solution, which is provided by Esteis (**only works *with* ConTeXt**). 
For "[overkill](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/overkill-is-a-good-thing/)" here a non-ConTeXt solution (**only works *without* ConTeXt**):

In the document's preamble:

```
\setvalue{name}{1}
```

or some other "harmless" value, just to have the value set for the first compilation run.

In the document

```
\getvalue{name}
```

and later in the document:

```
\makeatletter%
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\setvalue{name}{value}}%
\makeatother%
```

which writes `\setvalue{name}{value}` into `\jobname.aux`. (The `\string` is necessary, because the `\setvalue` command shall be written and not executed, e.g. `\string\thepage` writes `\thepage`, while `\thepage` would write the page number, for example `49`.) When the document is compiled for the next time, the `.aux` file (this time containing the `\setvalue{name}{value}`) is processed after `\setvalue{name}{1}` at the beginning of the document (really immediately before the content of `\AtBeginDocument{...}`), and `\setvalue{name}{value}` is executed (before `\getvalue{name}`). The `.aux` file is also processed between `\AtEndDocument{...}`'s content and `\end{document}`, but this has no effect for this case here.

Comment: -1 Context neither uses an `aux` file, nor supports the macros you mention.

Comment: @Marco: Thanks! I did not know ConTeXt was such a different TeX. I have added an according "header"-note to my answer. OK?

Comment: +1 for the most condensed explanation on how to use the `.aux` file mechanism.  :-) You might want to describe a bit more precisely, when exactly the `.aux` file is processed.

Comment: @Daniel: OK, done!