# Saving values for a second pass compilation

Tags: context

How can I save values (states) to be used on a second pass compilation?

For example, look at this simple example:

```
\definecounter[foox]
\setcounter[foox][1]

\definestartstop
    [foo]
    [before={\textrule[top]{Foo: \rawcountervalue[foox]}},
     after={\incrementcounter[foox]}]

\starttext

Total of Foos: \rawcountervalue[foox]

\startfoo \stopfoo
\startfoo \stopfoo
\startfoo \stopfoo

\stoptext
```

How can I make `Total of Foos:` print 3? Of course I don't want to be counting the amount of `startfoo ... stopfoo` manually

In latex, `\immediate\write` seems to do the trick

**EDITED**

As a bonus, is there any way to save marks on text to be used later? For example (using an hypothetical command `\setmark`):

```
\startfoo \setmark{x} \stopfoo 
...
```

where the values in `\setmark{...}` could be used early?

```
\definecounter[foox]
\setcounter[foox][1]

\definestartstop
    [foo]
    [before={\textrule[top]{Foo: \rawcountervalue[foox]}},
     after={\incrementcounter[foox]}]

\starttext

Total of Foos: % those marks where retrieved from the text
   Foo 1 -> mark1
   Foo 2 -> mark2
   Foo 3 -> mark3

\startfoo \setmark{mark1} \stopfoo
\startfoo \setmark{mark2} \stopfoo
\startfoo \setmark{mark3} \stopfoo

\stoptext
```

I hope I make this clear enough.

Comment: You can print the last value of the counter with `\lastcountervalue[<NAME>]` or `\convertedcounter[<NAME>][type=last]`.

Comment: @Metafox very nice. I didn't know this command. Thanks. But as an adendum, I update the question. Is there any way to get that kind of behaviour?

Comment: I guess both of these are related to the question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52067/storing-and-retrieving-data-in-tuc-file and http://wiki.contextgarden.net/System_Macros/Key_Value_Assignments#Multi-pass_data

Comment: @Metafox I think you should put your comment as an answer. This was what I was first looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All counters which are created with `\definecounter` are stored in the auxiliary file and ConTeXt already provides commands to access the last value it. If you just want to print the last value in your document you can use `type=last` in the second argument of `\convertedcounter`.

```
\definecounter [amadeus]

\startbuffer [amadeus]
  \starttabulate[|l|l|][before=,after=]
  \NC First value    \EQ \convertedcounter [amadeus] [type=first]    \NC\NR
  \NC Previous value \EQ \convertedcounter [amadeus] [type=previous] \NC\NR
  \NC Current value  \EQ \convertedcounter [amadeus]                 \NC\NR % \convertedcounter [amadeus] [type=number]
  \NC Next value     \EQ \convertedcounter [amadeus] [type=next]     \NC\NR
  \NC Last value     \EQ \convertedcounter [amadeus] [type=last]     \NC\NR
  \stoptabulate
\stopbuffer

\define\ShowAmadeus
  {\incrementcounter[amadeus]
   \starttextrule{Amadeus \convertedcounter [amadeus]}
   \getbuffer[amadeus]
   \stoptextrule}

\starttext
\dorecurse{5}{\ShowAmadeus}
\stoptext
```

[image: Printing the first and last values of a counter]

If you want to use these values to with calculations (e.g. with `\numexpr`) you have to use the following commands with give you the raw values of the counter which means no formatting or conversion is applied to them.

```
\definecounter [amadeus]

\startbuffer [amadeus]
  \starttabulate[|l|l|][before=,after=]
  \NC First value    \EQ \firstcountervalue [amadeus] \NC\NR
  \NC Previous value \EQ \prevcountervalue  [amadeus] \NC\NR
  \NC Current value  \EQ \rawcountervalue   [amadeus] \NC\NR
  \NC Next value     \EQ \nextcountervalue  [amadeus] \NC\NR
  \NC Last value     \EQ \lastcountervalue  [amadeus] \NC\NR
  \stoptabulate
\stopbuffer

\define\ShowAmadeus
  {\incrementcounter[amadeus]
   \starttextrule{Amadeus \convertedcounter [amadeus]}
   \getbuffer[amadeus]
   \stoptextrule}

\starttext
\dorecurse{5}{\ShowAmadeus}
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 1):

After the comment of @Metafox, and after I found these links: [Storing and retrieving data in tuc file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52067/storing-and-retrieving-data-in-tuc-file) and [System Macros/Key Value Assignments](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/System_Macros/Key_Value_Assignments#Multi-pass_data) I derived a solution from the problem, which stores the states in the .tuc file:

```
\definecounter[foox]
\setcounter[foox][1]

\definedataset[foo]
\setdataset[foo][total={\lastcountervalue[foox]}]

\define[1]\SetMark{
    \setdataset[foo][pos={\rawcountervalue[foox]}, mark={#1}]
}

\definestartstop
    [foo]
    [before={\textrule[top]{Foo: \rawcountervalue[foox]}},
     after={\incrementcounter[foox]}]

\starttext

Total of Foos:

\dostepwiserecurse{2}{\datasetvariable{foo}{1}{total}}{1}
    {Foo \datasetvariable{foo}{\recurselevel}{pos} -> \datasetvariable{foo}{\recurselevel}{mark}\blank}

\startfoo \SetMark{mark1} \stopfoo
\startfoo \SetMark{mark2} \stopfoo
\startfoo \SetMark{mark3} \stopfoo

\stoptext
```

Snapshot:
[image: Results]